# $A/m_a \simeq B/m_b$? Where $A,B$ are local rings, $A\subset B$ and $m_a\subset m_b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

I'm currently reading a math book in french so I'm translating everything as I go and also proving the remarks made throughout.

One remark that I haven't been able to prove is: if $A$ and $B$ are local rings with respective maximal ideals $m_a$, $m_b$ such that $A\subset B$ and $m_a=A\cap m_b$, then the residue fields $ A/m_a$ and $B/m_b$ are isomorphic.

I defined $\phi:A/m_a\to B/m_b$ such that $\phi(x+m_a)=x+m_b$. I didn't have any issue proving that its well defined, a morphism and injective. I coudn't prove its surjective though, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: But it's not correct... Counter-example: the prime $(3)$ of the integers remains prime in the Gaussian integers $\mathbb Z]\sqrt {-1}]$ (in number theory lingo, the prime remains inert). The residue field is $\mathbb F_9$, not $\mathbb F_3$ - you can localize the Gaussian integers and the integers at $(3)$ first to match your hypotheses; it won't change anything. [See "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions" for more on this.] Could you give the book, and include the exact text of the 'problematic' remark, so that we can be of more help?

Comment: Maybe I translated wrong then...Yes of course the book is valuations by Michel Vaquie, the exact text is:_Soient $A$ et $B$ deux anneaux locaux d'idéaux maximaux respectifs max(A) et max (B), nous disons que $B$ domine $A$ si $A\subset B$ et  max(A)= A max(B)....La relation "$B$ domine $A$", que nous notons $A\leq B$, est una relation d'ordre sur l'ensemble des anneaux locaux. Si nous avons  la relation $A\leq B$, alors l'injection de $A$ dans $B$ définit un isomorphisme du corps résiduel k($A$)=$A$/max($A$) sur un sous-corps du corps résiduel k($B$)=B/max($B$)_

Comment: Yes, you mis-translated - or you missed a word: "sous-corps" is subfield. They are saying that the residue field $k(A)$ is (isomorphic to) a subfield of $k(B)$.

Comment: BTW, the reason localisation won't change anything in 'my' example is that $R_p/pR_p$ is the quotient field of $R/p$. So if $p$ is already a maximal ideal, or equivalently $R/p$ is a field, one can identify the two quotient rings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposition is wrong, I had mistranslated the remark. As peter a g pointed out in the comments there is a counter example.